# JDBC connection failure: java.sql.SQLException: Communication link failure: Bad handshake

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection

I'm a newbie to JDBC. I just encountered a SQLException while I was trying to connect my java program with Mysql database.

Please find the details of run time error below :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Communication link failure: Bad handshake
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.init(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.connectionInit(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.Connection.connectionInit(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at databaseexample.DatabaseExample.connect(DatabaseExample.java:40)
    at databaseexample.DatabaseExample.main(DatabaseExample.java:26)
/home/sreejith/.cache/netbeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1

Program Details :
package databaseexample;
import java.sql.*
```

;

```
public class DatabaseExample {

    static boolean flag = false;
    static String DBURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb";


    static String  CHECK_SQL_QUERY = "SELECT 1";
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        flag =  connect();
        if(flag == true)
        {
            System.out.println("Connnected !");
        } else
        {
            System.out.println("not connected.");
        }



    }

    public static boolean connect() throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DBURL,"root","root");

        return true;
    }

}
```

I have tried to telnet port 3306 and received a result as below:

```
sreejith@desktop:~$ telnet localhost 3306
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
[
5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1*4` `iw2)Ml,L*
                                         Lmysql_native_password

!#08S01Got packets out of orderConnection closed by foreign host.
```

I'm running on ubuntu 16.04 by the way.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: check possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql

Answer (score -1):

Try this way:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Connection
{
    private static java.sql.Connection connection;

    public Connection(String serverAddress, String database, String user, String pass) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + serverAddress + ":3306/" + database;
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
    }

    public java.sql.Connection getConnection()
    {
        return connection;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a suggestion rather than an answer to the question posted by OP, doesn't qualify for an answer!

Comment: How is this different from the code used by the OP? Hint: in essence it is the same.

Comment: Hi Ramin.. I have tried with your code and still I'm facing the same error :( .. could someone could some way resolve this issue ? Is it the problem with the database connection string ?